# Creating global methods using templates that accepts single object as parameter in C++

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have two classes Circle{float getArea()} and Rectangle{ float getArea()}. These two classes are not related to each other. I want to create a global method using templates that accepts a single object as a parameter and displays the area of the corresponding object.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class area
{
 public:T getarea(T a);
        T getarea(T a, T b);
};

template<class T>
T area<T>::getarea(T a) 
{
 return(3.14*a*a);
}

template<class T>
T area<T>::getarea( T a,T b)
{
  return(a*b);
}

main()
{
area<float> a;
a.getarea(5);
a.getarea(2,4);
}
```

Comment: what is your question ? why do you have the tag UML ? I do not see the interest of the template here, it seems more interesting to have an abstract class having the abstract method *getArea* (and *getaCircumference* etc) and having both Circle and Rectangle implementing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the call to the object:

```
#include<iostream>

class Circle{
private:
    float m_r;
public:
    Circle(float r): m_r(r) {}
    float getArea() {return 3.14*m_r*m_r;}
};
class Rectangle{
private:
    float m_a, m_b;
public:
    Rectangle(float a, float b): m_a(a), m_b(b) {}
    float getArea() {return m_a*m_b;}
};

class area {
public:
    template<typename T>
    // static float area:getarea(T a);
    static decltype(std::declval<T>().getArea()) getarea(T a);
};

template<class T>
// float area:getarea(T a) {
decltype(std::declval<T>().getArea()) area::getarea(T a)  {
    return(a.getArea());
}

int main() {
    Rectangle r(2, 4);
    Circle c(5);
    std::cout << area::getarea(r) << '\n';
    std::cout << area::getarea(c) << '\n';
}
```

With `decltype`/`declval` the different instances of `area::getarea` can have different return types depending on the classes.